# mysql search query on one to many tables

Tags: mysql, search, full-text-search, one-to-many

i have two table (_video, _video_tag) like this.

i how to building a best search query ?

i want search in this fields (title, description, tag)

```
mysql> describe _video;
+-------------+---------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field       | Type          | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+-------------+---------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |
| user_id     | int(11)       | NO   | MUL | NULL              |                |
| image       | varchar(255)  | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| source      | varchar(255)  | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
| duration    | int(11)       | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| title       | varchar(255)  | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| slug        | varchar(255)  | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| description | text          | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| order       | int(11)       | NO   |     | 0                 |                |
| hit         | int(11)       | NO   |     | 1                 |                |
| status      | enum('0','1') | NO   |     | 1                 |                |
| date_add    | timestamp     | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                |
+-------------+---------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+

mysql> select * from _video_tag limit 5;
+----------+------------------------------------+
| video_id | tag                                |
+----------+------------------------------------+
|    17748 | cevahir almanca dersi              |
|    17748 | genis aile                         |
|    17748 | ulvi                               |
|    17748 | cevahir                            |
|    17749 | oyle bir geçer zamanki
+----------+------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to get, providing which information. However, I assume you want to get information `from _video` given a specific tag in `_video_tag`. Then you do

`select v.* from _video_tag as vt left join _video as v on v.id = vt.video_id where vt.tag = 'Specify tag';`

Comment: i also search in title and description. your query only search in tag

Answer (score 0):

If your tables are MyISAM The best scalable way is to make a FULLTEXT index on title and description in _video table:

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX title_desc ON _video( title, description )
```

and one on tag column in _video_tag table:

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX tag ON _video_tag( tag )
```

and then query like this:

```
( SELECT *,
  MATCH(title, description) AGAINT('some query string') AS relevance
  FROM _video
  WHERE MATCH(title, description) AGAINT('some query string') )
UNION
( SELECT v.*
  MATCH(vt.tag) AGAINST('some query string') AS relevance
  FROM _video_tag AS vt
  INNER JOIN _video AS v ON( v.id = vt.video_id )
  WHERE MATCH(vt.tag) AGAINST('some query string') )
ORDER BY relevance DESC
```

Comment: noboddy thank for your answer, but this query contain any syntax errors "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS relevance ) ORDER BY relevance DESC' at line 10"

Comment: thank you. remaing a problem. this query results contain duplicate rows :( how to solve this problem